# Drawing black-box circuits

Tags: tikz-pgf

Is there a simple way to draw blackbox circuits in latex where I can connect lines to the inputs and outputs? The assignment is to draw a 4-bit CPU, so I'm trying to find a clean way to specify everything.

An example of a full-adder blackbox circuit:

[image: Full-adder blackbox]

Comment: Have you tried with the `circuitikz` package ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just an idea. The main problem will be to adjust labels position inside main node.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
    fulladder/.style={draw, minimum size=3cm,
    label={[xshift=8mm]left:$c_\text{out}$},
    label={[yshift=5mm]below:$s$},
    label={[xshift=-6mm]right:$c_\text{in}$},
    label={[yshift=-3mm, anchor=center]65:$b$},
    label={[yshift=-3mm, anchor=center]115:$a$},
    }]

    \node[fulladder] (a) {};
    \node[fulladder, right=1cm of a] (b) {};

    \draw[<-] (a.115) --++(90:0.5cm) node [above] {$a_1$};
    \draw[<-] (a.65) --++(90:0.5cm) node [above] {$b_1$};
    \draw[<-] (b.115) --++(90:0.5cm) node [above] {$a_0$};
    \draw[<-] (b.65) --++(90:0.5cm) node [above] {$b_0$};
    \draw[<-] (b.east) --++(0:0.5cm) node [right] {$0$};
    \draw[<-] (a.east) -- (b.west);
    \draw[->] (a.west) --++(180:0.5cm) node [left] {$c$};
    \draw[->] (a.south) --++(-90:0.5cm) node [below] {$s_1$};
    \draw[->] (b.south) --++(-90:0.5cm) node [below] {$s_0$};

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

**Update: Easily adjusted labels**

I've learned how to better adjust labels inside nodes from [Torbjørn's](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/278407/1952) answer to 
[How to draw architecture with tikz](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/278349/how-to-draw-architecture-with-tikz).

Previous code with new label's declaration could be:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
    fulladder/.style={draw, minimum size=3cm,
    label={[anchor=west]left:$c_\text{out}$},
    label={[anchor=south]below:$s$},
    label={[anchor=east]right:$c_\text{in}$},
    label={[anchor=north]65:$b$},
    label={[anchor=north]115:$a\vphantom{b}$},
    }]

    \node[fulladder] (a) {};
    \node[fulladder, right=1cm of a] (b) {};

    \draw[<-] (a.115) --++(90:0.5cm) node [above] {$a_1$};
    \draw[<-] (a.65) --++(90:0.5cm) node [above] {$b_1$};
    \draw[<-] (b.115) --++(90:0.5cm) node [above] {$a_0$};
    \draw[<-] (b.65) --++(90:0.5cm) node [above] {$b_0$};
    \draw[<-] (b.east) --++(0:0.5cm) node [right] {$0$};
    \draw[<-] (a.east) -- (b.west);
    \draw[->] (a.west) --++(180:0.5cm) node [left] {$c$};
    \draw[->] (a.south) --++(-90:0.5cm) node [below] {$s_1$};
    \draw[->] (b.south) --++(-90:0.5cm) node [below] {$s_0$};

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]