# How to draw architecture with tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-styles, charts

I'm learning tiKz packages for the drawing of charts etc in LaTex but I have to draw an architecture that is quite difficult for me.

I need to draw the architecture in the figure below and, in addition, draw the modules in alignment.
Can anyone help me?

[image]

Comment: Alas, the only easy way to do this is to put entire tikzpictures inside nodes.  If this causes a problem, you can use saveboxes.

Comment: @JohnKormylo Why so?

Comment: What do you have so far? What have you tried? Can you post the code you've got for parts of the diagram? What are you stuck on specifically? Right now, we know you've hit a stumbling block, but we have no idea where so it is hard to target help appropriately in order to help you over the obstacle. Seeing the code you've got would tell us precisely where you need help or what's going wrong.

Comment: @JohnKormylo I disagree, it shouldn't be much of a problem placing the description-nodes, and the surrounding boxes can be drawn with the `fit` library.

Comment: @Torbjørn T. - Fit will solve the sizing problem, but not the aligning problem.  But if you place coordinates at the centers, align them relative to each other, then align everything else to them, that would work. But you would have to fudge all the distances.

Comment: @JohnKormylo For some definition of by hand, e.g. `\node[below=of desc4,xshift=2cm] (desc6) {Description 6};` and similar for description 5, then `\node[fit=(desc5)(desc6)]{};`. Or perhaps simpler, use a `\matrix` for each module that has "subnodes".

Comment: @JohnKormylo Fudging distances is probably better than nesting pictures, though.

Answer (score 6):

Probably needs some work and may not fit with your existing approach, but something like this might work:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=10pt]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,fit,shapes.arrows,shadows}
\newcounter{module}
\setcounter{module}{0}
\renewcommand*\themodule{\Alph{module}}
\tikzset{%
  module/.style={rounded corners, align=center, font=\sffamily, thick},
  simple module/.style={module, top color=blue!10, bottom color=blue!35, draw=blue!75, text width=40mm, minimum height=15mm, drop shadow},
  square module/.style={module, draw=orange!75!black, minimum height=20mm, text width=20mm},
  long module/.style={module, draw=orange!75!black, minimum height=20mm, text width=50mm},
  combo module/.style={module, draw=blue!75!black},
  simple module/.pic={
    \stepcounter{module}
    \node (module \themodule) [simple module] {Module \themodule};
  },
  module down arrow/.style={module arrow, shape border rotate=-90, yshift=1.25mm},
  module right arrow/.style={module arrow, xshift=-1.25mm},
  pics/horizontal module/.style n args=2{
    code={
      \stepcounter{module}
      \coordinate (c) at (0,0);
      \node [module right arrow] at (c) {};
      \node (module \themodule-1) [square module, left=7.5mm of c] {#1};
      \node (module \themodule-2) [square module, right=7.5mm of c] {#2};
      \node (module \themodule-3) [below=1.5mm of c |- module \themodule-2.south, module] {Module \themodule};
      \node (module \themodule) [fit=(module \themodule-1) (module \themodule-2) (module \themodule-3), combo module] {};
    }
  },
  pics/vertical module/.style n args=2{
    code={
      \stepcounter{module}
      \coordinate (c) at (0,0);
      \node [module down arrow] at (c) {};
      \node (module \themodule-1) [long module, above=7.5mm of c] {#1};
      \node (module \themodule-2) [long module, below=7.5mm of c] {#2};
      \node (module \themodule-3) [above=1.5mm of module \themodule-1.north, module] {Module \themodule};
      \node (module \themodule) [fit=(module \themodule-1) (module \themodule-2) (module \themodule-3), combo module] {};
    }
  },
  module arrow/.style={single arrow, single arrow head extend=2.5mm, drop shadow, draw=gray!75, inner color=gray!20, outer color=gray!35, thick, shape border uses incircle, text height=1.5mm, text width=2.5mm, anchor=center},
}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \pic {simple module};
  \node [module down arrow] at ([yshift=-7.5mm]module A.south) {};
  \pic [below=27.5mm of module A.south] {horizontal module={Description 1}{Description 2}};
  \node [module right arrow] at ([xshift=7.5mm]module B.east) {};
  \pic [right=42.5mm of module B.east] {vertical module={Description 3}{Description 4}};
  \node [module down arrow] at ([yshift=-7.5mm]module C.south) {};
  \pic [below=27.5mm of module C.south] {horizontal module={Description 5}{Description 6}};
  \node [module down arrow] at ([yshift=-7.5mm]module D.south) {};
  \pic [below=17.5mm of module D.south] {simple module};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: modules and arrows]

## EDIT

This version adds a little more depth and tries to simplify placement somewhat:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=10pt]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,fit,shapes.arrows,shadows,backgrounds}
\newcounter{module}
\setcounter{module}{0}
\renewcommand*\themodule{\Alph{module}}
\tikzset{%
  module/.style={rounded corners, align=center, font=\sffamily, thick, fill=white},
  simple module/.style={module, top color=blue!10, bottom color=blue!35, draw=blue!75, text width=40mm, minimum height=15mm, drop shadow},
  square module/.style={module, draw=orange!75!black, inner color=white, outer color=orange!75!black!5, minimum height=20mm, text width=20mm},
  long module/.style={module, draw=orange!75!black, inner color=white, outer color=orange!75!black!5, minimum height=20mm, text width=50mm},
  combo module/.style={module, draw=blue!75!black, inner color=white, outer color=blue!75!black!5, drop shadow},
  simple module/.pic={
    \stepcounter{module}
    \node (module \themodule) [simple module] {Module \themodule};
  },
  module down arrow/.style={module arrow, shape border rotate=-90, yshift=1.25mm, anchor=north},
  module right arrow/.style={module arrow, xshift=-1.25mm, anchor=west},
  pics/horizontal module/.style n args=2{
    code={
      \stepcounter{module}
      \coordinate (c) at (0,0);
      \node (arrow \themodule-1) [module right arrow, anchor=center] at (c) {};
      \node (module \themodule-1) [square module, left=2.5mm of arrow \themodule-1.west] {#1};
      \node (module \themodule-2) [square module, right=2.5mm of arrow \themodule-1.tip] {#2};
      \node (module \themodule-3) [below=1.5mm of c |- module \themodule-2.south, module] {Module \themodule};
      \scoped[on background layer]{\node (module \themodule) [fit=(module \themodule-1) (module \themodule-2) (module \themodule-3), combo module] {};}
    }
  },
  pics/vertical module/.style n args=2{
    code={
      \stepcounter{module}
      \coordinate (c) at (0,0);
      \node (arrow \themodule-1) [module down arrow] at (c) {};
      \node (module \themodule-1) [long module, above=2.5mm of arrow \themodule-1.north] {#1};
      \node (module \themodule-2) [long module, below=2.5mm of arrow \themodule-1.tip] {#2};
      \node (module \themodule-3) [above=1.5mm of module \themodule-1.north, module] {Module \themodule};
      \scoped[on background layer]{\node (module \themodule) [fit=(module \themodule-1) (module \themodule-2) (module \themodule-3), combo module] {};}
    }
  },
  module arrow/.style={single arrow, single arrow head extend=2.5mm, drop shadow, draw=gray!75, inner color=gray!20, outer color=gray!35, thick, shape border uses incircle, text height=1.5mm, text width=2.5mm, anchor=center},
}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \pic {simple module};
  \node (arrow AB) [module down arrow, below=5mm of module A] {};
  \pic [below=15mm of arrow AB.tip] {horizontal module={Description 1}{Description 2}};
  \node (arrow BC)  [module right arrow, right=5mm of module B] {};
  \pic [right=30mm of arrow BC.tip] {vertical module={Description 3}{Description 4}};
  \node (arrow CD) [module down arrow, below=5mm of module C] {};
  \pic [below=15mm of arrow CD.tip] {horizontal module={Description 5}{Description 6}};
  \node (arrow DE) [module down arrow, below=5mm of module D] {};
  \pic [below=5mm of arrow DE.tip] {simple module};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: modules and arrows]

Answer (score 5):

The `matrix` approach may have some limitations, but it makes it quite simple to set up a similar structure.

I shamelessly borrowed and adapted some styles from cfr's answer. The arrows are added using a couple of loops, makes it easier to fine tune the position collectively.

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,matrix,shapes.arrows}

\tikzset{
  modulematrix/.style={draw=blue!50!red,rounded corners,matrix of nodes,row sep=1cm,column sep=1cm,nodes={draw=green!70,align=center,font=\sffamily},inner ysep=0.5cm},
  module/.style={rounded corners, align=center, font=\sffamily, thick},
  simple module/.style={module, top color=blue!10, bottom color=blue!35, draw=blue!75, text width=40mm, minimum height=15mm},
  module down arrow/.style={module arrow, shape border rotate=-90},
  module right arrow/.style={module arrow},
module arrow/.style={single arrow, single arrow head extend=2.5mm, draw=gray!75, inner color=gray!20, outer color=gray!35, thick, shape border uses incircle, anchor=tail,minimum height=0.7cm},
}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node [simple module] (mA) {Module A};
\matrix[modulematrix,below=of mA,label={[anchor=south]below:Module B}] (mB) {Description 1 & Description 2 \\};
\matrix[modulematrix,right=of mB,nodes={text width=5cm,align=center},label={[anchor=north]above:Module C}] (mC) {Description 3 \\ Description 4 \\};
\matrix[modulematrix,below=of mC,label={[anchor=south]below:Module D}] (mD) {Description 5 & Description 6 \\};
\node [simple module,below=of mD] (mE) {Module E};

\foreach \n in {mA,mC-1-1,mC,mD}
  \node[module down arrow,below=1mm of \n] {};

\foreach \n in {mB-1-1,mB,mD-1-1}
  \node[module right arrow,right=1mm of \n] {};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is how to do it using saveboxes.  I also stole cfr's arrow style.

Note, when you rotate the arrows it also rotates the anchors (north, east,...).

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,shapes.arrows}

\tikzset{big arrow/.style={single arrow, single arrow head extend=2.5mm,
  draw=gray!75, inner color=gray!20, outer color=gray!35, thick,
  shape border uses incircle, minimum height=0.7cm,outer sep=2mm}}

\newsavebox{\boxa}
\newsavebox{\boxb}
\newsavebox{\boxc}
\newsavebox{\boxd}

\begin{document}

\savebox{\boxa}{%
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node (A) {Label 1};
  \node[big arrow,rotate=-90,below right] at (A.north west) {};
  \node[big arrow,rotate=-90,above right] at (A.north east) {};
\end{tikzpicture}}

\savebox{\boxb}{%
\begin{tikzpicture}[font=\tiny]
  \node (A) [draw=orange,rounded corners,minimum height=2cm, minimum width=2cm] {Description 1};
  \node (B) [big arrow,right] at (A.east) {};
  \node[draw=orange,rounded corners,minimum height=2cm, minimum width=2cm,right] at (B.east) {Description 2};
  \node[below] at (A.south) {\normalsize Module B};
\end{tikzpicture}}

\savebox{\boxc}{%
\begin{tikzpicture}[font=\tiny]
  \node (A) [draw=orange,rounded corners,minimum height=1.5cm, minimum width=4cm] (A) {Description 3};
  \node (B) [big arrow,rotate=-90,right] at (A.south) {};
  \node[draw=orange,rounded corners,minimum height=1.5cm, minimum width=4cm,below] at (B.east) {Description 4};
  \node[above] at (A.north) {\normalsize Module C};
\end{tikzpicture}}

\savebox{\boxd}{%
\begin{tikzpicture}[font=\tiny]
  \node (A) [draw=orange,rounded corners,minimum height=2cm, minimum width=2cm] {Description 5};
  \node (B) [draw=orange,rounded corners,minimum height=2cm, minimum width=2cm,right=1cm] at (A.east) {Description 6};
  \node[above] at ($(A.north)!.5!(B.north)$) {\normalsize Module C};
\end{tikzpicture}}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\node (A) [draw=blue,fill=blue!20,rounded corners,minimum height=2cm,minimum width=4cm] {Module A};
\node (B) [below] at (A.south) {\usebox{\boxa}};
\node (C) [draw=blue,rounded corners,below] at (B.south) {\usebox{\boxb}};
\node (D) [big arrow,right] at (C.east){};
\node (E) [draw=blue,rounded corners,right] at (D.east) {\usebox{\boxc}};
\node (F) [big arrow,rotate=-90,right] at (E.south) {};
\node (G) [draw=blue,rounded corners,below] at (F.east) {\usebox{\boxd}};
\node (H) [big arrow,rotate=-90,right] at (G.south) {};
\node (I) [draw=blue,fill=blue!20,rounded corners,minimum height=2cm,minimum width=4cm,below] at (H.east) {Module D};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: tikzpicture with saveboxes]